# Renaming outputs with iterative ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, mosaic-dataset

My model is meant to create mosaic datasets within a gdb. I am using the "For" function, and setting it to 6. The output correctly creates 6 mosaic datasets, each with the prefix T.

I would like these to have a different name, grabbing the name of the gdb and then _# (so G_057329641020_01_1, G_057329641020_01_2, etc.). How can I add the renaming function?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you are asking. If you are looking to add the name of a GDB automatically, you must want to loop over a bunch of them, otherwise you'd just manually place the name of the GDB in the file name....

I can only think in code now, try opening IDLE and run the following:

```py
import arcpy, os

location = r'c:\temp'

#Create Mosaic Dataset Parameters:
in_workspace = r'c:\temp\x.gdb'
coordinates = 'NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_11N'
num_bands = ''
pixel_type = ''
product_definition = ''
product_band_definitions = ''

number_of_loops = 6

for (dirpath, _, filenames) in os.walk(location):
    if dirpath.endswith('.gdb'):
        x = len(dirpath.split('\\'))
        dataset_name = (dirpath.split('\\')[x-1]).replace('.gdb','')
    while number_of_loops > 0:
        arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management(in_workspace, dataset_name + str(number_of_loops), coordinates, num_bands, pixel_type, product_definition, product_band_definitions)
        number_of_loops -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a 2 step process you could do to get the output name *"filegdbname_mosaic_dataset_number"* i.e. *"G_057329641020_01_1"*

**Step 1:**
Use the Parse Path model only tool to get the file gdb name.  Make sure to set **"Name"** as the *Parse type.*

[image]

**Step 2:**
You have already partially done this step, in that you have used the *"For"* iterator to generate a numberical value as the outputof the iterator. (I have renamed the tool output below from "Value" to "Iteration" to avoid confusion with the above image)

[image]

As the output name for your mosaic dataset, you can now use [inline variable substition](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-inline-variable-substitution.htm) to create the output name.

Using my 2 images above, my output name would be *%Value%_%Iteration%*
This would give me output names of:

Samplepoints_1

Samplepoints_2

Samplepoints_3

etc...